# .NET - Merge Tables not overwriting

Tags: .net, merge, datatable, overwrite

In my winform app, I am merging two tables using the following code:

```
            ldtDestinationData.Merge(ldtSourceData, False, MissingSchemaAction.Add)
```

But the issue is RowState of my SourceData table is Added and the rowstate of my DestinationTable is Modified; hence it's not overwriting values in Destination table.

Below is a reference, I got from msdn which proves what I said above:

> If the incoming row has a RowState of Added, and the existing row has a RowState of Unchanged, Modified, or Deleted, the RowState of the existing row is set to Modified. Also, the data from the Original row version of the existing row is not overwritten with data from the incoming row, because the incoming row does not have an Original row version.

Is there a way to overwrite the changes in destination table somehow OR if there is a way to change the row state of my source table so that the changes in the destination table can be overwritten?

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.. I got the solution i.e. AcceptChanges commits the changes made to the table and changes the rowstate to Unchanged, which makes it possible to overwrite changes in the destination table.